# How do you reverse a gradient from any one color to any other color

Tags: gradient

If I have a gradient, know color a (primary) and b (secondary), how would I go about reversing said gradient so color a instead transitions into an equivalent alpha that when layered over a pure background of color b would producing the starting gradient.

To further elaborate, say I have this gradient:

[image: test gradient]

And I want to split to so that I have this instead:

[image: The primary color]

Where if I overlay it with this:

[image: the secondary color]

I get back to this:

[image: back to the start]

I have been only able to get it work with the primaries at best. My math doesn't seem to work on anywhere else but the calculator (will post if requested), any ideas?

EDIT: I should explain that the software in question is irrelevant, as this is a concept that I want to put into a plugin. The colors are in ARGB scale from 0-255 each (Ox12345678)

Comment: what is the software you are using? and this gradient is it for web or for printed output?

Comment: @hsawires Software is irrelevant, and I'm talking about pixels here in the typical ARGB scale. Should edit that into my question.

Comment: This seems to be what e.g. the Color to alpha filter of GIMP is able to achieve - remove one color from an image and replace it with the appropriate level of transparency, so that if it is overlayed over a layer filled with the color, you get the same image. So having a lot at this filter's code might help.

Comment: @MichaelSchumacher It seems so indeed. I will have to look deeper at it as the way it's coded confuses the heck out of me. Once I test it out fully and work it mathematically out, I will answer my own question (provided a better answer doesn't exist by then)